# Usage of SPI inside an ISR

Tags: interrupt, spi, isr

I learned, that SPI-code uses interrupts. So is it true then, that I can't use SPI related code inside an ISR?

Background: I want to capture one or more revolution speeds with an MCP23S17. I rewired the interrupt lines to INT1 and INT2 accordingly to get the interrupts at the Arduino.

I thought it was good to fetch the port registers from the MCP23S17 inside the ISR, but this apparently doesn't work.

Is the only thing I can do in my ISR set a flag for another test in the main loop? And let a routine called from lood() then poll the registers from the port expander? This opposes the idea to fetch the relevant data which issued the interrupt ASAP.

Comment: This is why you don't use port expanders for timing-sensitive applications.

Comment: And instead of port expanders i shall use what?

Comment: Real IO pins on the microcontroller.

Comment: @Majenko: Which I have to poll. :(

Comment: No you don't - there's such a thing as Pin Change Interrupt which is (IIRC) available on *every* IO pin.

Comment: Reads interesting. Is the only difference between those Pin Change Interrupts and INT0/1 the fact that the latter can additionally trigger on high and low?

Comment: Please post your code. Majenko is perfectly correct. SPI does not use interrupts, at least during `SPI.transfer()`. *I learned, that SPI-code uses interrupts.* - where did you learn that?

Comment: `apparently doesn't work.` - I hate that expression. What happened? What did you expect to happen? In what way did they differ?

Comment: As a sidenote. You can use interrupts inside an ISR. Just call `sei();` at the beginning of the ISR. There are however some side effect that you have to know about. It's therefor generally advised not to do this, unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: @NichGammon: The ISR is never called. To control the behaviour of the ISR I let it increase a global counter. But the counter stays at 0, while the INTCAP register of the port expander shows evidence for activity. But considering the answers here, the error must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SPI doesn't use interrupts.  It references the interrupt flag to know if a transfer has been completed, but it doesn't actually have interrupts enabled:

```
SPDR = data;
asm volatile("nop");
while (!(SPSR & _BV(SPIF))) ; // wait
return SPDR;
```

It should be perfectly possible to use SPI within the interrupt - indeed there is portions of the SPI API that deal specifically with this - see https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPIusingInterrupt for instance.

Comment: Ok, I missed that. Then there must be another thing I apparently have botched...